# Are microtubules in centrioles helical, like they are when in isolation?

Tags: molecular-biology, proteins, protein-structure

Microtubules tend to be of a helical structure, do microtubules in centrioles also have a helical structure?

[image]

The centriole is composed of nine circularly arranged triplet microtubules, one complete microtubule (the A-tubule) onto which two additional partial microtubules are assembled (the B- and the C-tubules, respectively. )

What are the structures of A, B and C respectively, are they helical?

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm aware, microtubules that are composed of the same constituents will always be structurally identical. This will probably help you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centriole There's a couple of nice diagrams

Comment: plenty of diversity,
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5662251/